# Same code doing two different things on two different apps?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, browser, webbrowser-control

If I have this code:

```
class TestBrowser : WebBrowser
{
    public TestBrowser()
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Controls.Add(panel);
    }
}
```

Should the panel cover the `WebBrowser` and make it invisible or not? What would it be the expected behavior? I ask this because this same code is giving me two different results on two different apps and can't find why (the panel covers it on one and is invisible in the other).

Comment: Dunno, but can you fiddle with some kind of z-index?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add new controls to the 
- add and ID to the panel
- define a function that will change the Dock property value after adding controls to the panel itself contained in the instance of TestBrowser